# MYSQL Trigger - update values in table from other table before insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

What I am trying is to update a value before insert from another table - here is what I've got:

2 Tables

```
hbrpg_geo{
...
id INT       //id that needs to be written into hbrpg_person
zip VARCHAR(10) //contains postcode
...
}

hbrpg_person{
...
 fk_postcode     // initially it's filled with UK postcode - but trigger should change value to id of hbrpg_geo of matching postcode (hbrpg_geo.zip). 
...
}
```

Trigger:

```
...

BEGIN
    DECLARE NP_VAR integer;
    DECLARE OP_VAR TEXT;
    SET OP_VAR = NEW.fk_postcode;
    SET TE_VAR = OP_VAR;
    SELECT hbrpg_geo.id INTO NP_VAR FROM hbrpg_geo WHERE hbrpg_geo.zip = OP_VAR;
    SET NEW.fk_postcode = NP_VAR;
END
```

It all appears to be working apart from:

```
SET OP_VAR = NEW.fk_postcode;
```

If I replace NEW.fk_postcode with a valid UK postcode in quotes (i.e.: "W1 3XX") it works fine and the trigger replaces the field fk_postcode with the id of hbrpg_geo table.

What I am doing wrong ? How can I assign the value of NEW.fk_postcode to the variable I just declared?

Comment: You do know the new new fk_postcode value will be an INT not something of the form "W1 3XX" right?  (It'll also apparently be a DB auto-increment column and mostly meaningless)  Perhaps there's another field of hbrpg_geo that you could use?  zip?  Except then you'd merely be validating whether it was there and not changing it.

Comment: Seems to me that you may as well use the postcode as a natural key into your `hbrpg_geo` table and (potentially) do away with the synthetic `id` key.

Comment: Forgot to add that fk_postcode is a integer.

Comment: @eggyal: I thought so too - however, the postcode table is fairly big. I do not update the person table very often so I don't mind waiting to have a row inserted or updated. However, if I have to compare two varchar characters in a table with thousands of entries - that takes ages. It's simply faster if I have two integers to match.

Comment: @GeorgeAstonishing: That depends on your indexes... correctly indexed, joining on `VARCHAR` columns may well satisfy your performance criteria.

Comment: @eggyal: To index UK postcodes I thought of indexing the first 3-4 characters. It takes stil seconds - considering that the site has 4000+ vistors per day (peak time afternoon) it might compromise the quality of the site. I manually tested comparing integers and the performance was way better (milliseconds).

Comment: UK postcodes comprise at most 7 (significant) characters.  That's 7 bytes of ASCII.  56 bits.  Even if one includes the (insignificant) whitespace, it's still only 64 bits.  On a 64-bit processor, a whole match can be performed in a single CPU cycle.  Integers cannot be any faster.  I say use the postcodes as (fully indexed) natural keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the sequence of assignments:

```
SET OP_VAR = NEW.fk_postcode;
. . .
SET NEW.fk_postcode = NP_VAR;
```

The column `new.fk_postcode` has the same type.  But the columns are, respectively, `text` and `integer`.

You need to fix the type incompatibility.  My guess is that `fk_postcode` is actually an integer and separate from the value (which would be a string).

Comment: I think the object of the trigger is to look into a foreign table for the given string and replace with its synthetic (integer) key, all occurring invisibly within the `INSERT` command.

Comment: @eggyal . . . The question is, What is the type of `fk_postcode`?  If it is an integer then there are problems.  If it is a character string then it might work.

Comment: I guess it is (or at very least, ought to be) FK referencing `hbrpg_geo.id` and therefore an integer.  But what problems do you foresee with this?  Does MySQL perform type checking prior to running `BEFORE` triggers?  I've not tried it, but I assume not.  After the trigger has run, even if MySQL still has the input typed as a string, it will be implicitly cast to integer just as if a literal string value `'123'` was provided to an integer column.  Or won't it?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - ohhh, it is an integer :( Ok that explains why it doesn't work. So the user types in for example "W1 3XX" - the database field is an integer. So how do I compare the value "W1 3XX" to the zip field in hbrpg_geo.zip and write the corresponding hbrpg_geo.id into the fk_postcode field? Is there a way to do this ?